# Getting the value of TD in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have this code which show me the list of my item

```
<tbody class="table-color2">
    <c:forEach var="defect" items="${defectList}">
        <tr>
            <td id="defectId"><a onclick="getDefectId()">${defect.id}</a></td>
            <td>${defect.createdDate}</td>
            <td>${defect.reportedBy.firstName}</td>
            <td>${defect.title}</td>
            <td>${defect.bugtype.description}</td>
            <td>${defect.status.description}</td>
            <td>${defect.priority.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

what Im trying to do is to get the value of the td `id="defectId"` when it is clicked, my jquery script for the onclick is this :

```
function getDefectId(){
    var defectId = $(' #defectId ').val();
    alert("Defect ID " + defectId);
}
```

but currently, I'm getting a value of undefined, how do I get the value?

Answer (score 4):

You have several issues. Firstly you're appending the same `id` in a loop, which will result in duplicates which is invalid. Also, `a` elements don't have a value to retrieve so you need to use `text()`. Finally note that using your current method would mean that you need to pass the `this` reference of the clicked element to the function.

However you can tidy all that up by using classes and hooking up the event in JS. Try this:

```
<tbody class="table-color2">
    <c:forEach var="defect" items="${defectList}">
        <tr>
            <td class="defect"><a href="#">${defect.id}</a></td>
            <td>${defect.createdDate}</td>
            <td>${defect.reportedBy.firstName}</td>
            <td>${defect.title}</td>
            <td>${defect.bugtype.description}</td>
            <td>${defect.status.description}</td>
            <td>${defect.priority.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.defect a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ckx1u07q/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this : use `text()` instead of `val()` because you want to know the text inside `td` and not the value of `input` element.

**EDIT**: - Sorry, missed that there are multiple td's. In this case, you must not use same id for all tds. Just make it class and do following changes in function.

```
function getDefectId(){
   var defectId = $('.defectId').text();
  alert("Defect ID" + defectId);
}
```

I would suggest to use jQuery event handler instead of calling javascript function. See below code

HTML: remove onclick call

```
<td class="defectId"><a href="#">${defect.id}</a></td>
```

jQuery : register a click handler and read text

```
$(function(){
   $('.defectId a').click(function(){
      var defectId = $(this).text();
      alert(defectId);
   });
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff, thanks for pointing the issue. I have made correction in answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following(remember that `id` needs to be unique):

```
<td class="defectId"><a onclick="getDefectId(${defect.id})">${defect.id}</a></td>
```

And in you `function`:

```
function getDefectId(value){
  alert("Defect ID " + value);
}
```